# Read month from Mongoose data using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose

`I have the problem to get the name of the month from mongoose database using node js

```
<Select native className={'selectdropdown'} onChange={this.onSelectOption}>
  <option value={-1}>ALL MONTHS</option>
  {monthNames.map((name, i) => {
    return (
      <option value={name} key={i}>
        {name}{' '}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</Select>
```

Comment: It's neither node.js  nor mongoose.

Comment: In your devtools network panel, are you able to verify whether the request is successful and data is being returned? Do you have access to the backend where the DB query is made? If so, can you confirm that the month data is being returned? If it is, you might instead be having issues with your fetch request.